# Getting rid of warning messages when calling LSOF in Travis

Tags: travis-ci

I have a unit test that calls [`LSOF`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/lsof.8.html) to get the number of open file handles. It runs fine on my machine, but on Travis builds ([such as this one](https://travis-ci.org/abbeycode/UnzipKit/jobs/67869115#L336)) I get this warning:

> lsof: WARNING: can't stat() vmhgfs file system /Volumes/VMware Shared Folders
>         Output information may be incomplete.
>         assuming "dev=2d000003" from mount table

I did some searching, and [it looks like the fix](http://blog.infrageeks.com/tuning-os-x-on-esxi/) is to add this line to the advanced settings (or vmx file) for the machine's image:

```
isolation.tools.hgfs.disable=TRUE
```

Could someone please take a look at adding this?

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into similar issue - https://superuser.com/questions/1082701/osx-on-vmplayer-running-on-windows-10-smb-shared-files-keep-getting-resource

Tried `isolation.tools.hgfs.disable=TRUE`. Sharing seems to be still enabled, but the problem persists.